# Как сделать из двух переменных одну?

Tags: php

Есть допустим переменная:

`$select_id` *(её содержимое это число 2, это динамично, так что данные именно из неё надо брать, но на данный момент пускай будет 2)*

И куча переменных с однородными названиями.

*К примеру `$num_0, $num_1, $num_2, ..., $num_n`*

Так вот, как мне можно используя частицу `$num_` добавить значений с `$select_id`
Пробовал `$num_.$select_id` на теперь понимаю что оно работает не так. Может я вообще думаю не в том направлении.

Comment: Объявите переменную $num массивом. `$num[$select_id] = $select_id`. После чего (к примеру $select_id = 2) сможете обращаться к ней $num[2]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Этот способ тоже не плох. Но всё же мне кажется через переменную в переменной всё же лучше)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать понятие [Переменная в переменной](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php):

```
    <?php
        $select_id = 2;
        $num_2 = 'hello';
        $key = 'num_' . $select_id;
        echo $$key;  /* hello*/
    ?>
```

хотя думаю вам необходимо задуматься о рефакторинге логики своего кода.. ))

Comment: Спасибо. Всё работает. Возможно действительно стоит задуматься о том что-бы навести порядки)